# Typescript - RequireJS - Internal module is not defined

Tags: module, requirejs, typescript

I am trying to do an SPA with Typescript and I would like to use a module constructed within multiple files. Here is the code I did:

**salut.ts**

```
module salut {
    export class salut1 {
        public Title = "salut1";
    }
}
```

**salut2.ts**

```
module salut {
    export class salut2 {
        public Title = "salut 2";
    }
}
```

**MyApp.ts**

```
/// <reference path="salut.ts" />
/// <reference path="salut2.ts" />

class MyApp {
    constructor() {
        var salut1 = new salut.salut1();
        var salut2 = new salut.salut2();
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    var app = new MyApp();
};
```

Visual Studio Intellisense informs me that there is no error in the code, meanwhile, when I start the application, I have the following error in the console:

Uncaught ReferenceError: salut is not defined.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Javascript ordering in TypeScript : https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts#javascript-generation-and-ordering

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `<script>` tags for `salut.js` and `salut2.js` *above* the tag for `MyApp.js`, or compile using `--out` so that there's only one .js file.

Comment: This is working perfectly well, is it possible to use require js to load these files? In development I would use separated files while using merged file in production?